# Long boot times Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, dmesg

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. Boot takes about 90 seconds, which is far longer than it ought to be. If I run `dmesg` there's two "jumps" that are apparent. The first is:

```
[    2.876292] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   34.123020] EXT4-fs (sdb5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

sdb5 is my boot drive; an ssd. `fdisk -l` output is

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
/dev/sdb3        2048 250068991 250066944 119.2G  5 Extended                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
/dev/sdb5        4096 250068991 250064896 119.2G 83 Linux
```

Not really sure why it'd take so long to mount that filesystem - that's my first question - how do I diagnose the problem mounting that disk?

The second jump in time is here:

```
[   39.440877] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[   83.788740] Could not find key with description: [391e121390deac97]
[   83.788743] process_request_key_err: No key
[   83.788744] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [391e121390deac97]
[   83.788745] One or more global auth toks could not properly register; rc = [-2]
[   83.788746] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]
```

Which I think is something to do with mounting an encrypted directory; is that right? If so it's probably a broken KDE plasma vault as my home directory is not encrypted, so I'll just bin that vault.

Edit: output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @4.648s
└─multi-user.target @4.648s
  └─kerneloops.service @4.638s +9ms
    └─network-online.target @4.637s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @2.464s +2.172s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.136s +326ms
          └─dbus.service @2.070s
            └─basic.target @2.065s
              └─sockets.target @2.065s
                └─snapd.socket @2.059s +5ms
                  └─sysinit.target @2.059s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.935s +123ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.917s +16ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.913s
                          └─home-djrscally.mount @14.042s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @270ms
                              └─keyboard-setup.service @177ms +93ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @169ms
                                  └─system.slice @168ms
                                    └─-.slice @167ms
```

And `systemd-analyze blame` is:

```
  8.653s apt-daily.service
  2.338s apt-daily-upgrade.service
  2.172s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  1.370s dev-sdb5.device
  1.285s mariadb.service
  8.653s apt-daily.service
  2.338s apt-daily-upgrade.service
  2.172s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  1.370s dev-sdb5.device
```

That's every entry above a second

Comment: Hello djrscally , and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add the output of following commands to your post.  `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: @abu_bua added! Neither is jumping anything out at me, but then I don't know what I'm doing!